# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении изображение двигалось?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на изображение оно начинало беспрерывно прыгать вверх вниз пока не отведешь от него курсор?

Может есть вариант, как сделать это на js или jquery без подмены статичного изображение анимированным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно есть такой вариант. Используйте [CSS-анимацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation):

```css
img:hover {
  animation: jump 1s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes jump {
  50% { transform: translateY(-20px); }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/103/200/150">
```